# Make a hint with dots for password EditText? [Android]

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to make a hint for password EditText. How to put dots as hint with the same style as transformed characters in password EditText?

Comment: simple do this way edittext.setHint(".......");

Comment: `android:hint="......."`

Comment: Thanks, but will it have the same look as transformed characters in password EditText?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing what you mean is you want the password typed to appear as dots. You can use the password attribute for the EditText in your xml :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/account_password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:password="true"/>
```

If you really want the hint (what appears to the users before they type in the EditText) as dots, you can use this attribute :

```
android:hint="........"
```

Comment: @user3264399, indeed :) Done !

Comment: @2Dee will it have the same look as transformed characters in password EditText?

Comment: @Taras, I don't believe so. I would personally consider that having dots as a hint is not such a good UX. Nevertheless, you could *maybe* achieve that by playing with font sizes using a TextWatcher (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) but I'm not sure, haven't tried it...

Comment: @2Dee, Thanks! for making middle dots we can use the following Unicode code: \u00B7

Comment: this is deprecated.